# How do i use the ForeignKey in Choices?

Tags: python, django

Here is my models.py

```
class Devtool(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='이름')
  kind = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='종류')
  content = models.TextField(verbose_name="개발툴 설명")

class Post(models.Model):
  #   devtool_CHOICES = (
  #     ('django', 'django'),
  #     ('react', 'react'),
  #     ('spring', 'spring'),
  #     ('node.js', 'node.js'),
  #     ('java', 'java'),
  #     ('C++', 'C++'),
        devtool = models.ForeignKey(choices=Devtool.name, verbose_name="예상 개발툴", null = True)
```

I want to replace devtool_CHOICES to "Devtool.name"
How can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe:

```py
class Devtool(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='이름')
    kind = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='종류')
    content = models.TextField(verbose_name="개발툴 설명")
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Post(models.Model):
     devtool = models.ForeignKey(
         Devtool, verbose_name="예상 개발툴", null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL
     )
```

Comment: Then... where is Choices?? I want to make "DROPDOWN menu"

Comment: Just insert some data into the devtool table

Comment: I don't know how to make 'dropdown menu' in that code. Didn't that need """models.ForeignKey(choices= ........ )""" <- this code?

Comment: @손병우 You don't need to add a choices tag for the foreign keys. Foreign key by default is a drop-down field in Django. Also, can you tell me where do you want to use this drop-down field?(In admin panel or Django templates) If you want to use it in Django templates are you using Django forms?